# Single-event vs multiple-event probability?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I may be asking something basic, but would nevertheless appreciate the answer.

Say, for example, we have 10 trials of the event with a single-event probability of success that equals 0.5. I want to find out what is the likelihood of having at least 5 successes.

The binominal calculator says it's ~0.623. However, shouldn't you expect there to be a 100% likelihood of at least 5 successes out of 10 trials in the long run? I mean, if you do an infinite number of such 10-trial sets, it would essentially be the same as doing an infinite number of single trials, right?

Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean "100% likelihood?"

Comment: The probability of five successes does not represent the possibility that we would have at least five successes in one of those trials.  Instead, if we conducted a million trials, we would expect to obtain at least five successes in around $623,000$ of those trials.  The actual number might be considerably larger or smaller than that, but the percentage error would likely be small.